# Not able to declare String type accumulator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to define an accumulator variable of type String in Scala shell (driver) but I keep getting the following error:-

```
scala> val myacc = sc.accumulator("Test")
<console>:21: error: could not find implicit value for parameter param: org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam[String]
       val myacc = sc.accumulator("Test")
                                 ^
```

This seems to be no issue for Int or Double type of accumulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because Spark by default provides only accumulators of type `Long`, `Double` and `Float`. If you need something else you have to extend `AccumulatorParam`.

```
import org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam

object StringAccumulatorParam extends AccumulatorParam[String] {

    def zero(initialValue: String): String = {
        ""
    }

    def addInPlace(s1: String, s2: String): String = {
        s"$s1 $s2"
    }
}

val stringAccum = sc.accumulator("")(StringAccumulatorParam)

val rdd = sc.parallelize("foo" :: "bar" :: Nil, 2)
rdd.foreach(s => stringAccum += s)
stringAccum.value
```

**Note**:

In general you should avoid using accumulators for tasks where data may grow significantly over time. Its behavior will similar to `group` an `collect` and in the worst case scenario can fail due to lack of resources. Accumulators are useful mostly for simple diagnostics tasks like keeping track of basic statistics.

Comment: val accum = sc.accumulator(0)(SparkContext.IntAccumulatorParam) 
 for integer accumulator.