# Spark: run an external process in parallel

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is it possible with Spark to "wrap" and run an external process managing its input and output?

The process is represented by a normal C/C++ application that usually runs from command line. It accepts a plain text file as input and generate another plain text file as output. As I need to integrate the flow of this application with something bigger (always in Spark), I was wondering if there is a way to do this.

The process can be easily run in parallel (at the moment I use GNU Parallel) just splitting its input in (for example) 10 part files, run 10 instances in memory of it, and re-join the final 10 part files output in one file.

Comment: Instead of splitting input see if you can use named pipes: parallel --pipepart --fifo -a bigfile yourprg --input {} --output {#}.out  This way you can save disk I/O by not splitting bigfile first. Maybe even as output: parallel --pipepart --fifo -a bigfile yourprg --input {} --output '>(cat)' > merged.output

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thanks. I will have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to write a simple wrapper which takes data from standard input, writes to file, executes an external program, and outputs results to the standard output. After that all you have to do is to use `pipe` method:

```
rdd.pipe("your_wrapper")
```

The only serious considerations is IO performance. If it is possible it would be better to adjust program you want to call so it can read and write data directly without going through disk.

Alternativelly you can use `mapPartitions` combined with [`process`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package) and standard IO tools to write to the local file, call your program and read the output.

Comment: I cannot change that program as it is a "commercial black box" application. Anyway it looks like Spark cannot "parallelizing" the process as gnu-parallel does right?

Comment: Well,  you can, but compared to GNU parallel it will be rather cumbersome. If you cannot touch external application then one way or another you'll have to write a whole write-call-read routine.

Answer (score 1):

If you end up here based on the question title from a Google search, but you don't have the OP restriction that the external program needs to read from a file--i.e., if your external program can read from stdin--here is a solution.  For my use case, I needed to call an external decryption program for each input file.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import sys.process._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val showSampleRows = true
val bfRdd = sc.binaryFiles("/some/files/*,/more/files/*")
val rdd   = bfRdd.flatMap{ case(file, pds) => {  // pds is a PortableDataStream
    val rows   = new ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]()
    var errors = List[String]()
    val io     = new ProcessIO (
        in  => {  // "in" is an OutputStream; write the encrypted contents of the 
                  // input file (pds) to this stream
            IOUtils.copy(pds.open(), in)  // open() returns a DataInputStream
            in.close
        },
        out => {  // "out" is an InputStream; read the decrypted data off this stream.
            // Even though this runs in another thread, we can write to rows, since it
            // is part of the closure for this function
            for(line <- scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(out).getLines) {
                // ...decode line here... for my data, it was pipe-delimited
                rows += line.split('|')
            }
            out.close
        },
        err => {  // "err" is an InputStream; read any errors off this stream
            // errors is part of the closure for this function
            errors = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(err).getLines.toList
            err.close
        }
    )
    val cmd       = List("/my/decryption/program", "--decrypt")
    val exitValue = cmd.run(io).exitValue  // blocks until subprocess finishes
    println(s"-- Results for file $file:")
    if (exitValue != 0) {  
        // TBD write to string accumulator instead, so driver can output errors
        // string accumulator from @zero323: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31496694/215945
        println(s"exit code: $exitValue")
        errors.foreach(println)
    } else {
        // TBD, you'll probably want to move this code to the driver, otherwise
        // unless you're using the shell, you won't see this output
        // because it will be sent to stdout of the executor
        println(s"row count: ${rows.size}")
        if (showSampleRows) {
            println("6 sample rows:")
            rows.slice(0,6).foreach(row => println("  " + row.mkString("|")))
        }
    }
    rows
}}
```

```
scala> :paste "test.scala"
Loading test.scala...
...
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[62] at flatMap at <console>:294

scala> rdd.count  // action, causes Spark code to actually run
-- Results for file hdfs://path/to/encrypted/file1:  // this file had errors
exit code: 255
ERROR: Error decrypting
my_decryption_program: Bad header data[0]
-- Results for file hdfs://path/to/encrypted/file2:
row count: 416638
sample rows:
  <...first row shown here ...>
  ...
  <...sixth row shown here ...>
...
res43: Long = 843039
```

References:

- https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessIO.html
- https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-closures-in-scala-fp-examples#using-closures-with-other-data-types