# Collect data with Foreach

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, rdd

I'm trying to foreach an RDD and collect the data into a String builder. But it is not happening as foreach is running on executor nodes and string builder is running on driver node. is ter any way to achieve my objective ?  I dont want to use **collect** action as it is expensive one.

```
private static StringBuilder collect(JavaRDD<String> javaRDD) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        javaRDD.foreach(x -> builder.append(x));
        System.out.println(builder.toString() + " ****");
         return builder;
    }
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Review your apache spark knowledge regarding driver/workers (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html) : your (string)builder lives in the driver, your javaRDD lives on the workers. If you want to get data from the javaRDD into your builder, you need to 'collect()'.

Comment: You mean to say, ter is no way other than collect() ?

Comment: Updated my question. Thanks @WillemM

Comment: Yep. (or it's variant's like take(x))

Comment: Thank you. @WillemM

Comment: @BalajiReddy Can you let us know what makes you `collect` action is expensive from `foreach` action in above use case?

Comment: Foreach will be executed in executor/slave nodes where as when you call Collect() , all the data from the slave nodes will be pulled to driver program . It is not okay when you are dealing with TBs of data. I was wishing to have an alternative approach for my objective.

Comment: I know diff between `foreach` vs `collect` in general and thanks for your explanation again. But what I asked is diff in your use case where you are trying to build a string which is also not efficient if you build `string builder` with foreach. Lets say your rdd is 1TB big and can you guess what might be the size of `builder` you are returning?

Comment: For example , I have 1TB records and 4 slave nodes running. If i have foreach to generate string builders, then 4 stringbuilders will be created at slave nodes where as collect() will generate only one stringbuilder with 1TB of size.I will flush out data as soon as possible.Correct me if i'm wrong. @avr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreachPartition`. This will only collect data on the executor, not in the driver.

```
javaRDD.foreachPartition(partition -> {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  while (partition.hasNext()) {
    builder.append(partition.next());
  }
  System.out.println(builder.toString() + " ****");
});
```

Comment: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable...... getting this error at foreach loop " for(String x: partition) "

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Java API. Partition is an Iterator, not an Iterable. Try the new code.

Comment: Yes. I just tried with while loop. it works. this is what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rdd.aggregate in order to combine all the strings in your rdd into a single StringBuffer like so:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize( List( "h" , "a" , "b" ) )
val res = rdd.aggregate( new StringBuffer )( ( sb:StringBuffer , str : String ) => sb.append( str ) , ( sb1 : StringBuffer , sb2 : StringBuffer ) => sb1.append( sb2 ) )
println( res ) // "abh"
```

Obviously the entire content of strings of your rdd will be concatenated in the string buffer which has the potential of being huge but that's what you wanted...
This is better than collect because the string data is not shipped "raw" to the driver ( only in the concatenated form).

Also notice the order of strings is not guaranteed...

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be an alternative way: An Accumulator. Here is a redirect on how to use a String Accumulator:
[Not able to declare String type accumulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496509/not-able-to-declare-string-type-accumulator)
Credit goes to the author of that reply

Comment: Did not think of this option but won't using accumulators be a bit risky since if the rdd is computed more than once the accumulator value won't be correct?

Comment: @HarelGliksman You are right, unless you cache it. I shall edit the "better way" in "alternative way"

Comment: @HarelGliksman Accumulators are safe when calling inside an action such as `foreach`.

Comment: True Dikei, thought it's just worth mentioning the risk as foreach is not the only way someone might try to use them for this purpose...